# Will the Star Wars LCG game have Force power cards?

Tags: star-wars-lcg

Will the Star Wars Living Card Game have Force power cards, like Force lightning and Force push?

Comment: Your question is quite speculative. It's not really suitable for this site, where you should ask ["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face".](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @RoToRa, although this question is regarding the future, the game was previewed recently, and is slated for a Christmas launch (or early next year). Although, that is kind of what they said last time before they pushed the release. I personally don't like this question, because it feels like a promotional piece for FFG to get people to go out and watch their video.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. The [demo at GenCon 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HW-yEwnb0ws) featured at least [3 force power cards](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9867680#9867680), Force Lightning, Force Choke, and Force Rejuvination.